# One cucumber data table for multiple feature file/scenarios

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

I have a scenario where multiple feature files are using a similar set of data so I want to have one data table within the framework and refer it in multiple feature files/scenarios

Example: Suppose i have 2 feature files feature1 and feature2 both expecting signing data as test data. currently what i am doing is writing signing details in both feature files but I want common data table in one place. Is it possible in the cucumber framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data tables are typically associated strictly with a single `Scenario` (or `Scenario Outline`), so sharing across feature files is not possible. While it may seem annoying to have to replicate the data, it aids in keeping processing of the feature file simple, and aids in reading the content off as a human reader.

Comment: what if I use an excel file for test data and read test data in my cucumber scenario? Are there any limitations? what's your thought on this mitch

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from implementing a step like `Given some data from my_file.csv` or similar; however, it would be up to you to implement this step so your test can interpret it correctly. If your test vector was in fact, 10,000 rows of data, this would be preferable. But to reiterate, there is no way to share a data table between feature files, or even distinct scenarios, within the Gherkin syntax itself.